# Require Password after Login

Tags: windows-7, display, script, cmd.exe, lock

I have a SSD for boot up ands its fast. I do not want the computer waiting for me to load all of my programs and services. I am the only user on my account. Is there a way to require the password after login. Alternatively if there is no proper way of doing it, I have found that:

Lock Workstation:

```
Rundll32.exe User32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

could maybe also be used.
Is there a proper way of doing it in the windows. If not how can I have that command up there set to a startup script. If I were to go into Lock mode after login would in windows continue to run the start up procedures

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/219815/create-a-password-after-login?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put your rundll command in a .cmd file and put it or a shortcut into the Startup folder. Combined with an autologon you should achieve what you want to. I suppose the timeframe between autologon and lock is a security hole. Considering your scenario that might be negligable of course.

Comment: so I got the script to run when I login. THe things is how do i set up a password that doesn't prompt me on start up?

Comment: @user320 - You have two choices.  You can have Windows remember the password or you can supply the pasword yourself.  You won't be able to create a script to provide your password that would be a huge security vulerability.  Windows stores your password in a secure way.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatically-login-and-lock       THe most sutiable answer I found

Comment: Sysinternals Autologon (saves the password encrypted and provides an easy GUI way to do it): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx